# Why does the comb tool feel super weak?

Tags: hair, brushes

I'm trying to play around with hair, but when I use the comb brush on a parent curve it takes several strokes just to barely move it, even though the brush is at max strength.

I tried both the projected and sphere falloff, turning strength pressure and collision on and off, combing from different angles and distances, and even using different brush radius sizes, but nothing changes.

I've seen other posts about hair issues supposedly being solved by turning off Deflect Emmiter, but that option doesn't show on my comb brush setting.

Any ideas? I'm using a mouse, blender 3.5, and the hair strand has 8 segments.

Comment: Do you use the new *Curves* of Blender 3.x (*Sculpt* mode to edit them) or the old *Particle System* with hair particles (*Particle Edit* mode to edit them)? Only the old particle system has the *Deflect Emitter* option. I guess you are using the new hair curves since you have the *Sphere/Projected* falloff options. In both systems, the *Comb* brush only works for the control points. You need to touch them, not the lines between them. Unfortunately, you cannot see the points of the new hair curves in sculpt mode but you can make them visible with a GN modifier.